# "Each one of them" and "Every one of them"

Tags: pronouns

1 I gave **every one of them** a $10 tip when I checked out of the hotel.

2 I gave **each one of them** a $10 tip when I checked out of the hotel.

I am familiar with "each one of them". But I found #1 on BBC English learning website. Does sentences 2 is also correct?

3 He picked up forty of these publications and read **each one of them**.

In #3 can we replace "each" with "every" (as used in #1)

Comment: "every" subtly emphasizes how many you gave a tip to, and how generous you were, whereas "each" emphasizes that you gave it to all of them personally, one by one. For example,  you could leave a $50 bill and say "share this" and that would be tipping "every one of them" (or "everyone"), but if you went to each of them in turn and gave them a ten, you'd have tipped "each of them." it's a very subtle distinction and always interchanges,  but there can be a slight nuance, especially in writing.

Comment: the interesting – and tricky – thing is you can say 'each of them', but cannot say 'every of them'.

Answer (score 2):

1, 2 and 3 are all correct. Yes, in #3, you can replace "each" with "every."

(Source: Native speaker)

Answer (score 0):

**every:** for people or things considered as a group

**each:** for people or things considered separately

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! Please explain why your answer is correct; answers without explanation don't teach the patterns of English well and [may be deleted](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3294/18673).